# Detecting Popen() errors when shell=True

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to execute an arbitrary user-provided command in that user's `$SHELL`. The command may be short-lived (like `ls`) or long-lived (like `firefox`), and it may be a single command, a pipeline, or any other shell-supported construct.

The method of execution must indicate success or failure on behalf of the shell and *must not* block regardless of when or whether the command terminates. The command may *never* terminate until the method of execution returns and my program continues.

`Popen()` with `shell=True` does not block but also does not indicate failure. The `subprocess` helper functions do block and are not useful here. `Popen.poll()` (suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861548)) returns `None` until the command terminates and does not immediately return non-`None` on failure (it must be called repeatedly until the shell terminates).

As an example of the desired behavior

```
prog1 = shell_run('blocking_prog', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
prog2 = shell_run('nonsense_prog', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

the first line should assign a `Popen` object to `prog1`, the second line should raise an `OSError` or similar.

Am I correct in thinking that it is impossible to *reliably* detect `Popen()` errors under these conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your *actual problem*. What do you want to do? Why is something like `subprocess.check_call('date', shell=True)` not sufficient?

Comment: you can do [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) to get stderr output but it is unclear whether you actually need it.

Comment: It's not clear still whether the point of your question is to tell whether the shell failed to execute a command, or how to use .communicate(), or what situation you're talking about.

Comment: +1. Quite concise and detailed answer with quite nothing to complain.

Comment: @phihag Probably because of the `PIPE`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering your question directly, but using `plumbum` for such tasks can make your life so much easier. http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have to know if it failed in order to know whether to pipe data in or not, you could do

```
prog2 = shell_run('nonsenseprog', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
               shell=True, executable=os.getenv('SHELL'))
# If the program does not exist, it should fail immediately and .poll() knows about that.
# If it exists and runs, `.poll()` returns None.
if prog2.poll() is not None:
    raise Whatever # it failed
```

Alternatively, you could check if you really need `shell=True`.